# Is there a way in spring boot to override a request header on HttpServletRequest?

Tags: java, json, spring, request

I'm trying to validate when the user doesn't provide a content-type header as a header, I want to default it as application/json on the `HttpServletRequest`, is this possible? I don't see any methods that would suit that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new servlet filter that is applied before the one which troubles you. In this filter you do not pass down the original `request` instance the filter chain but instead wrap it in a `jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper` that you extend to provide your default headers if the original is missing such a header.

Something along the lines of:

```
public class HeaderDefaultsRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

    private final Map<String, String> headerDefaults;
    
    public HeaderDefaultsRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request, Map<String, String> headerDefaults) {
        super(request);
        this.headerDefaults = headerDefaults;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String getHeader(String name) {
        String header = super.getHeader(name);
        if (header == null) {
            // Also mind header casing here
            return headerDefaults.get(name);
        }
        return header;
    }
}
```

Also be sure to override `getHeaderNames()` and other stuff to create a consistent extension of that wrapper class.

Comment: I actually tried using this approach, but, for some reason, it returns me the following error: ```HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported```.

Comment: @CarryFlag without any further information and a reproducible example it's difficult to tell where youre problem originates from.

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly mention request header and validate the same

e.g.

```
@GetMapping("/action")
public ResponseEntity<String> doAction(@RequestHeader("Content-Type") String headerValue) {
    if (!headerValue.equals(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)) {
        // Throw exception
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok("Ok!");
}
```

Comment: Actually, I can't do this, because the validation gets before, on a filter, which has this HttpServletRequest